# I am getting an error $ionicPlatform.ready is not a function?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am getting error $ionicPlatform.ready is not a function,actually i am working on internet connection checking when the app is opened,i tried separate example for internet connection checking it is working fine,the same example is using and i tried to integrate the same example in my another example... it is getting error $ionicPlatform.ready is not a function,if i remove this line connection checking is not working .Please help me why i am getting that error.I added code bellow what i worked on example....

```
    Index.html
    -----------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
<ion-pane>
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
<h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
this is net connection testing example
</ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
</html>

app.js
--------------
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
if(window.Connection){
if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
alert("there is no internet connection"); 
$ionicPopup.confirm({
title: "Internet Disconnected",
content: "The internet is disconnected on your device."
})
.then(function(result) {
if(!result) {
ionic.Platform.exitApp();
}
});
}
}
});
})
```

Thank you....

Comment: The example that you have shown works perfectly. Are you getting error in this example?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking. Is it the code above that isn't working for you? Or is it when you put that code in a different example? As Alex Rumba mentioned, the above code does work.

Comment: if i am putting same example in another one it is getting error $ionicPlatform.ready function is not a function

Comment: guys will u please help me why i am getting that error